# What is the next prime of the form $F_n+F_{2n+1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Define $$f(n):=F_n+F_{2n+1}$$ where $F_n$ denotes the $n$ th fibonacci number.

Then , $f(n)$ is prime for $$n=1,4,6,12,78,348,366,432,732,864,934,1932,5700,9084,14038$$ and no other positive integer $n\le 41\ 000$

> What is the next prime of this form ? Can infinite many primes of this form be expected ?

Since small prime factors are apparently not forced and considering the growth rate, I think there are infinite many primes of this form.

Comment: This would make a nice addition to the OEIS.

Comment: Since even the much simpler question "Are there infinite Fibonacci primes?" is unsolved, I don't see much hope for this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some searching I found that $n=65070$ results in a prime (or at least a very PRP).

To this point (about 45 minutes in) I have found no other $n < 80000$ that results in a prime number.

---

**UPDATE:** A few minutes later the second new prime popped up! $n=84460$ also results in a PRP.

---

**UPDATE:** I found the third new PRP of this form, $n=110220$.
Also, these findings were the only ones with $n < 115000$.

---

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** The search limit now includes all $n < 200000$ without finding additional primes.

Comment: Great answer again (+1 and accept)